# 18.04 LTS Colors help: want to keep desktop scheme without making interfaces unusable

Tags: kubuntu, kde, themes, colors

Example below from Gimp, but it's not the only one. I like the overall color scheme I'm using in KDE, but several applications are almost unusable, whether it's black text in a black textbox or light gray background with only slightly lighter gray icons. Is it possible to fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Coming from a Windows environment, I'm not used to so many possibilities for customization. What I've learned today is that most apps in Linux can adjust their themes, something I never did in Windows. I selected a lighter theme in Gimp's own preferences, and have found the same option in other apps. Problem solved.